# ubuntu antivirus

Tags: security

- Why I need to use anti virus like `clam-av` `clam-tk` or **commodo
  anti virus** or any free anti virus in Ubuntu ?

  **Note**: if I've root login enabled.and  I am running few windows programs in`wine1.6`. will these  anti virus is of any use? when my windows program has virus infected executables...
- **Can those virus  written for windows affect Ubuntu OS files?**
- Why it is said that Linux platform is virus free ?
- Companies like symantec are making application like Norton anti virus for android   which is again also Linux based platform.

Comment: "I need to"? Who says you need to?

Comment: @muru i asked to myself :) like playing windows game infected with virus

Comment: See http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-1c91cac836dd52754c846d2ef62be4f346eebe87

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I need to use anti virus like clam-av clam-tk or commodo antivirus in Ubuntu

You do not. Anything with Ubuntu is optional. The only reason to install the software you mention is when your Ubuntu is the system in a network where software and  mails are sent to Windows machines. So for normal desktop users there is no need whatsoever.

> Can those virus written for windows affect ubuntu OS files?

Yes. But they need to be specifically created to target Ubuntu through WINE. There are curently zero examples of this type of virus. And even then you probably will need to provide your admin password at a moment where you did not expect it to be asked. Anything related to WINE is dubious anyways. I myself would always use something like vBox to use Windows software; or a dual boot.

> Why it is said that Linux platform is virus free ?

Because there has not been anyone that was able to create a virus that by itself is capable to create havoc amongst Linux systems. Linux was set up from the beginning to be multi-user. That also enforced that the creators had to come up with a concept that allows to prevent random users to do random things across the system. We Linux users have always been using an admin account (be it root or an admin with sudo) and separate user accounts. A pretty good show stopper for someone that is interested in affecting a lot of systems in the shortest amount of time without needing manual inteference.

In that respect: Windows is a lot easier target and Windows users have a lot less knowledge about computers and it uses.

> Companies like symantec are making application like Norton anti virus for android which is again also Linux based platform.

Have a look around the web and you will see that the people claiming you need anti-virus are mostly the anti-virus people. [Example](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/do-you-need-antivirus-on-android/). If you stick to the intended places where you can get apps an anti-virus is a waste of resources. Now if you mess with your hardware and install 3rd party software from dubious sites you are on your own.

Answer (score 2):

It is a lot harder to get a virus on Linux than Windows as the kernel code for each machine with Linux installed is different, even if you use the same CD or .iso image on another machine. With Windows the kernel code is the same. You can install an antivirus if you want for added security.  There are many FREE antivirus programs out there for Linux. Just be careful about the websites you go to. I have been using Linux, in multiple distributions, for years without an antivirus program and I have yet to get a virus of any kind.